# What's this slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

i Wanna Know what kind of Slider do they use in this Page ?
http://negarkhaneh.ir/
(that slider which is upper than Footer showing off pictures)
tnx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://negarkhaneh.ir/js/jquery.cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#NewsSlider').cycle({
fx: 'scrollHorz',
// timeout: 5000,
timeout: 6000,
speed: 300,
pause: 1,
//prev: '.NewsSliderPrev',
//next: '.NewsSliderNext',
pager: '.NewsSliderNav',
pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Right-click -> View Source. Script tag references 'jquery.cycle.js'. Therefore, the site uses the JQuery Cycle plugin, from malsup.com, found at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/